# Social network using text attributes in R

Tags: r, networking, text

I'm not sure if I can do what I want in R, but I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Book=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                 Character=c('Sally', 'Jessie', 'Linda', 'Sally', 'Jessie', 'Linda', 'Sally', 'Jessie', 'Linda'),
                 Target=c('Jessie', 'Sally', 'Jessie', 'Jessie', 'Sally', 'Sally', 'Jessie', 'Linda', 'Sally'),
                 Word=c('cool', 'good', 'like', 'time', 'good', 'like', 'time', 'good', 'like'),
                 Total=c(1,2,4,2,4,3,2,4,4),
                 AllTotal=c(5,10,11,5,10,11,5,10,11))
```

The 'Character' column is the person speaking the 'Word', and the 'Target' is the person being spoken to. Therefore, I have a directed network. I am trying to build a social network based on who uses which words when speaking with specific people. For example, Sally might only use certain words (let's say, 'cool'), when speaking with Jessie, whereas Jessie might use the word 'cool' all the time with everyone in the network.

(The 'Total' column is the number of times Character A says a word in a given book, whereas 'AllTotal' is the number of times Character A says a word across all books.)

I have used the R package 'textnets', but it is only clustering similar words overall, and does not consider who is saying what to whom. Is there a way to do what I want in this or another package?

```
install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)
install_github("cbail/textnets")
library(textnets)

textnet <- PrepText(df, groupvar = "Character", textvar = "Word", node_type = "groups", pos = "all")
text_network <- CreateTextnet(textnet)
VisTextNet(text_network, label_degree_cut = 0)
```

(The CreateTextnet function isn't working on this simple example, but works on my larger dataset that is set up the same way; I don't understand why).

I think what I need is to show that Sally --> Jessie, with the word 'cool' on the edge, whereas Jessie --> Sally and Jessie --> Linda with 'cool' on those edges.  Or maybe some kind of clustering plot where Sally and Jessie cluster around the word cool (but then I'd need to know who is using it toward whom, so I'm not sure if that'd work).

I used the package 'igraph' for the regular social network (excluding the Word data), but I don't know if I can add the Word data into this somehow.

```
install.packages('igraph')
library(igraph)
edgeDat <- graph.edgelist(as.matrix(df[,2:3]), directed=T)
plot(edgeDat)
```

Any thoughts on what this kind of network is called and how I might achieve it?

Comment: You can get pretty close with `g = graph_from_data_frame(df[,c(2:6,1)]); 
plot(g, edge.label=df$Word)`

Comment: This works so long as I limit the network to 2-3 words (I have a few thousand unique words in my data set). Any more than that and the visual is too messy to interpret.  But, this is close to what I wanted and may be the best I can do.

Comment: Yes.  A thousand labeled arrows between even a modest number of nodes will become hard to read.